Granting admin consent for Graph API permissions in Entra/Azure
I'm trying to get access for "Microsoft Graph Command Line Tools" working with delegated permissions. Is it not possible to login to the Entra/Azure and manually add graph permissions I want rather than having to wait either for another user or myself to use the app and request permissions to run that app and then allow after that happens?
For example, if I know I want the app to have delegated admin consent for something like Policy.Read.IdentityProtection (which is a permission that requires admin consent) then can I not just login and add that in the app registration here?

I am not currently using "admin consent workflow" which means users can't even request access to permissions that need admin-consent so it seems like I have to add Policy.Read.IdentityProtection to the scope request in the app, run the app while authenticating as an admin, then consent to that permission while granting it to the directory and then the app becomes stamped with that admin consent permission and I can see it in the portal.
But why can't I just add this permission manually in the portal instead of having to make the request from the app? Or can I actually do that and can't seem to figure out how?

Delegated permissions means code executes using the current user's security context. Which means it can do anything the user has permission to do, including  things the user might not want to do.
The user has to convey trust in the app by consenting via a dialog in order to allow the app to assume their identity.
This is for the user's and for the org's protection and it's baked into the Oauth protocol, so you'll see that pattern all over the internet.

That is fine but what I'm trying to figure out is whether I can just add permissions which require admin-consent manually as an administrator in the portal rather than waiting for them to requested by a user (whether that user is an admin or not).
If I try to authenticate to the app as an admin and request a scope that needs admin-consent, I can immediately grant access and also grant for the directory during the login step. Can I not just, as an admin, add specific permissions in the portal manually instead of waiting for them to be requested by some other use (whether myself or another)?

I have tested and know for a fact that as a non-admin user trying to run "Microsoft Graph Command Line Tools" that when I attempt Connect-MgGraph with scopes that need admin-consent, I can't consent to these permissions since they don't exist in the directory yet and I am stuck with the "ask an administrator to do this" message (since I'm not using admin consent workflow).
I have to then login as an admin, request the same scopes, accept on behalf of the tenant, and then my non-admin user can begin using the app with those higher admin-consent permissions.
